# Ant Design - Upload file into memory before posting

Tags: javascript, typescript, antd

In the Ant Design examples they set the `action` property to specify a server to upload a file to. I would like to instead upload into memory and then post the contents to my server.

The Ant Design examples look like this.

```
const uploadProps = {
  name: 'file',
  action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
};

return (<Upload {...uploadProps}></Upload>);
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the property `customRequest` of the Upload component ([Antd Upload](https://ant.design/components/upload/#API)). There you can obtain the file as a property.